# Assign a value to a variable

Tags: cobol

I am fairly new to COBOL and am trying to implement a program involving basic arithmetic operations. The one statement that is generating errors for me is :

```
Move (MULTIPLY UPrice BY OrdAmt) TO OrdCost
```

which gives me the following errors :

```
Move (MULTIPLY UPrice BY OrdAmt) TO OrdCost.
........^
%COBOL-W-BLKPREEND, Unreachable statement
at line number 36 in file USR$ROOT3B:[GPY]CLASS5A.COB;13

Move (MULTIPLY UPrice BY OrdAmt) TO OrdCost.
.............^
%COBOL-F-SYN7, Missing literal or data-name
at line number 36 in file USR$ROOT3B:[GPY]CLASS5A.COB;13

Move (MULTIPLY UPrice BY OrdAmt) TO OrdCost.
.......................................^
%COBOL-F-MISSING, "." required at this point
```

This statement lies within an a structure of if statements. What does `Missing literal or data-name` mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited you question to match the exact error message you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

You may be new to COBOL, but that doesn't absolve you from following its syntax.

The errors are generated by a sorely confused compiler.

There are a number of ways to do what you seem to want:

```
Do calculation storing result
Copy result to where you want it to go

Do calculating, storing result where you want it to go
```

The second is more normal for COBOL programmers:

```
MULTIPLY UPrice              BY OrdAmt
  GIVING                     OrdCost.
```

I've left the full-stop/period on the statement, because I think you have an old '74 Standard compiler.

However, if, as you say, this code is within "a structure of if statements" then the full-stop/period is going to break your structure, so take it off.

You need to get hold of a COBOL manual/your course-notes/a good COBOL book and get a firm grip on the basics of the language.

Be aware that MULTIPLY A BY B produces a result and stores it somewhere, there is no concept of it producing "a result" in the way that an assignment statement of some type may.

Be also aware that ADD A TO B, SUBTRACT A FROM B and DIVIDE A BY B do so as well, and all allow the use of GIVING which puts the result somewhere else.

There is also the COMPUTE verb, which is an assignment-type. Between these five verbs, you can achieve a great deal of nuance. Indeed, search here for "COBOL nuance" for a recent answer for some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do that is using the verb COMPUTE. Something like:

```
COMPUTE RESULTVAR = VAR1 * VAR2.
```

That way you can use simpler symbols like *+-/. Hope it helped.

Comment: Simpler than what, or in what way? If @user209396 were to have a job working with COBOL programs, you suggestion would be for them to change all the existing program-stock to use COMPUTE, or what? Those are terrible data-names, why didn't you the ones from the question?

Comment: It was just an example, so anyone  could understand. Apparently I failed to do so, I'm sorry, COBOL Prince.

Comment: Well, if you expand on it, and use the original names, and indicate it can't be used within the MOVE, then it would be a worthwhile contribution. Our OP is very uncertain about COBOL (and they've left the building) and I don't think they'd realise that the COMPUTE contains an implicit MOVE, or that the target can be numeric-edited, and that ROUNDED can be specified, and suchlike. And answer covering those things would be useful. Your Highness.